# Select Next and previous row data SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I want to ask on how to get the next and previous data when I select the "8787"

This is the sample data on table Name:

NameId is not auto number.

```
NameID    RName
6767      Apple
8787      Hallow
8627      Orange
```

Thanks

Comment: Define next and previous - do you want the data for the next and previous NameID?

Comment: Actually yes. I want the prev and next NameID

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get the next ID, throw away all IDs that are not larger, sort the table by the ID so that the next ID is the first one, then take only this one record:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE NameID > 8787
ORDER BY NameID
LIMIT 1
```

Similar for the previous ID:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE NameID < 8787
ORDER BY NameID DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on CL.'s answer, if you want it all in one query:

```
select a.*, 
  (select RName  
   from t1 b 
   where b.NameID < a.NameID 
   order by NameID desc limit 1) as prev_rname,
  (select NameID 
   from t1 b 
   where b.NameID < a.NameID 
   order by NameID desc limit 1) as prev_NameID,
  (select RName  
   from t1 c 
   where c.NameID > a.NameID 
   order by NameID asc  limit 1) as next_rname,
  (select NameID 
   from t1 d 
   where d.NameID > a.NameID 
   order by NameID asc  limit 1) as next_NameID
from t1 a
order by a.NameID;
```